# Where can I find a good jQuery drop shadow plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

Does anyone have a good recommendation for a drop shadow jQuery plugin?

I've been working on a project that had every element on the page with a subtle drop shadow, we started using [RUZEE](http://www.ruzee.com/blog/shadedborder/) to do the shadows but there was a severe performance hit when you had more then 4 or 5 shadows being calculated on the page.

I went to [writing my own plugin](http://ralphwhitbeck.com/2008/08/27/jQueryPluginSimpleShadow.aspx), I call it simple shadow and it only uses jQuery to inject images in floating div's around the div you want a drop shadow.  Nothing elegant but for the purpose of completing that site it worked without performance hits.

Now my plugin isn't anything special but I am still in search for a good light weight shadow plugin.

Answer (score 7):

CSS 3 will support drop shadow. Firefox and Safari are already supporting the feature.

You might want to use that instead of the jQuery functionality, since it will run in browsers who have turned off javascript.

Take a look at http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/ for a demo of the shadow.

Comment: Unfortunately, for most of us, that's not enough - IE is still the big market (for most sites).

Comment: This feature is also supposed in Chrome. And it's very nice too.

Comment: That's great for box shadows, but not text shadows in FF. :(

Answer (score 5):

The original site hosting the jQuery Dropshadow plugin has apparently gone down.

For anyone looking for it, [I'm currently hosting it on my Dropbox account](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1546882/jquery.dropshadow.js).

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery UI](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Shadow) also provides drop shadow functionality.

Comment: I was aware of this plugin.  the last time I checked it it still needed work.  But the last I heard it was dropped out of the official UI release.  Was it added back in?

Comment: says `drop shadow` is no longer part of official release? whatever happened to it.

Answer (score 1):

The JQuery UI no longer supports shadow functionality.

Answer (score 1):

try the FontEffect jQuery Plugin, sorry I can't post the link, but you can find it easily on google or jQuery plugin site.

Comment: It would appear that this works for text but not for DIVs.  Any ideas?