# Resizable drop shadows with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a JQuery plugin that supports adding resizable drop shadows to divs, tables, text, etc. I really only want the shadow to resize when the user resizes the browser window (the elements with the shadows are not draggable).

I've tried [this plugin](http://eyebulb.com/dropshadow/) but it doesn't seem to shrink the width of a shadow when a user narrows the browser window.

Thanks,
Don

Comment: There's also a delay in the time it takes the shadows to resize/move in the example when the browser windows size is changed - it looks pretty yucky, in my opinion

Comment: Yes, it's not very satisfactory, but it was the highest voted solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165446/where-can-i-find-a-good-jquery-drop-shadow-plugin

Answer (score 3):

If the shadows aren't absolutely critical, I'd suggest simply using CSS3's box shadows. They're supported on all recent versions of the major browsers except IE.

```
-moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px #000;
box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px #000;
```

About: http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/

The problem with JS-generated shadows (i.e. shadows made with jQuery) is that they're really slow to generate. They're generated pixel-by-pixel, appending the DOM with lots of markup. If you were to regenerate them while the browser's getting resized, it'd eat the user's CPU alive.

If you're brave and want to have resizable shadows no matter what browser the user is using, the *other* route to go would be using images and CSS to construct the shadows. This method'd be fully resizing-friendly:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/cssdrop2/