# A Good jQuery drop shadow plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

In my spare time am trying to learn javascript & jQuery. I generally experiment on a website. I want to achieve a faint shadow-effect when some element appears on the page. This gives -

1. This appears as if the element is above other elements on the page.
2. and makes this new element something important to look at.

How can I get this using jQuery. In some places, they were suggesting to use 'image sprites'. But I want to avoid images for this purpose because -

1. I don't want to be opening up photoshop everytime I want a shadow-effect for some new element.
2. Images take time to load. Hence as soon as the element appears on the page, it takes time to load the images & the shadow-effect illusion is gone by then.

Also, I hear CSS3 has this shadow-effect built-in. But there are different browsers out there using different versions. Plus IE* browsers are a majority. I want this to work in all versions of IE. How can I get this effect across most browsers as uniformly as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/DropShadow

This a reasonably good plugin!

You can see a demo here:

http://dropshadow.webvex.limebits.com/

Answer (score 7):

Someone else had the [exact same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165446/where-can-i-find-a-good-jquery-drop-shadow-plugin) <strike>just the other week</strike> two years ago. The selected answer was for an [unmaintained drop shadow plugin](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1546882/jquery.dropshadow.js) from 2007, but you may want to take a look at the other answers as well.

Though it's a matter of opinion, I believe that CSS3 is your best bet, providing **progressive enhancement** to those browsers that support it. Here's a sample set of dropshadow properties as shown on [CSS3, Please!](http://css3please.com/):

```
.box_shadow {
     -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #333; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #333; 
          box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #333; 
}
```

Comment: yeah I had a look at that link before I posted this Question. I discarded it primarily because it was asked 2 years ago. A Lot has changed since then, Plus I do not want to adopt an unmaintained code base at this point in my trials.

Comment: but what about IE? Majority of people still use IE.

Comment: IE9 supports the `box-shadow` property. For earlier versions of IE, you will need to use the arcane `blur` filter. That's about the closest you can get: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532979(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

I have already written a post on my blog on how to create jQuery drop shadow effect. You can [check it out here](http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2010/06/29/creating-drop-shadow-jquery-plugin/). The plugin basically creates a div behind those elements to be shadowed to create drop shadow effect. [See the demo of that old version here](http://sarfraznawaz2005.kodingen.com/demos/jquery/JQuery_dropshadow/).

I have now modified the plugin and it now uses **CSS3** for drop shadow effect for the browsers that support it or the same **div-based shadow** for non-supporting browsers. Here is the code:

```
/**
 * Drop Shadow Plugin jQuery
 * http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/
 * Author: Sarfraz Ahmed (sarfraznawaz2005@gmail.com)
 */

(function($){

    $.fn.dropshadow = function(settings){
        // Extend default settings
        var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.dropshadow.defaults, settings);

        // Check if CSS3 is supported
        var style = $('div')[0].style;
        var isCSS3 = style.MozBoxShadow !== undefined || style.WebkitBoxShadow !== undefined || style.BoxShadow !== undefined;

        return this.each(function(settings){
           var options = $.extend({}, opts, $(this).data());
           var $this = $(this);

            if (!isCSS3){
                var styles = {
                    position: 'absolute',
                    width: $this.width() + 'px',
                    height: $this.height() + 'px',
                    backgroundColor: options.shadowColor,
                    zIndex: options.shadowLayer,
                    top: ($this.offset().top + parseInt(options.distance, 10)) + 'px',
                    left: ($this.offset().left + parseInt(options.distance, 10)) + 'px'
                };
            }
            else{

                var boxshadow = options.distance + ' ' + options.distance + ' ' + options.blur + ' ' + options.shadowColor;
                var styles = {
                    position: 'absolute',
                    width: $this.width() + 'px',
                    height: $this.height() + 'px',
                    backgroundColor: options.shadowColor,
                    zIndex: options.shadowLayer,
                    top: $this.offset().top + 'px',
                    left: $this.offset().left + 'px',
                    MozBoxShadow:boxshadow,
                    WebkitBoxShadow:boxshadow,
                    BoxShadow:boxshadow
                };
            }

            $('<div>').appendTo($('body')).css(styles);

        });
    }

   // set default option values
  $.fn.dropshadow.defaults = {
    shadowColor: '#DFDFDF',
    shadowLayer: -1,
    distance:'5px',
    blur:'3px'
  }

})(jQuery);
```

Here is how to use it:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.shadow').dropshadow({
    shadowColor: '#cccccc',
    shadowLayer: -100,
    distance:'6px',
    blur:'3px'
  });
});
```